# Setting background image in javascript with base64 data

Tags: javascript, html, image, background-image

I'm having trouble setting the background image of a div using a data url. Here's my code, which doesn't throw an error but also doesn't work:

```
profilePhotoData= shout.get("authorProfPic");

src = 'data:image/png;base64, ' + profilePhotoData.base64

outerDiv.style.backgroundImage="url("+src+")";
```

Comment: Try removing the space inside the string after `base64,`

Comment: That didn't fix it unfortunately

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17090571/is-there-a-way-to-set-background-image-as-a-base64-encoded-image-in-javascript#answer-26295354

Comment: if your `div` has no content... thus no size... you wont see it.  Adding spaces or adjusting the `width` and `height` will allow you to see the background image. And you may need to scale the image, as you mentioned in your comment below. By setting a value for the `background-size` option. [Here is a run down](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this **css** works:

```css
body {
  background: #ffffff url("data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4...") no-repeat top left;
}
```

Thus maybe you should:

- try the **background** property.
- add the **"** between your url brackets

Comment: This worked when used in combination with backgroundSize: cover

Comment: Upvoted; this does work well. However, `background-image` works well too. `background` is just the shorthand version, here allowing you to set the no-repeat and location all at once. Check the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background?v=example) for shorthand of `background`. My point here is that this difference should have nothing to do with it.Also, I have never needed the `"` between the url parenthesis for encoded data strings. For Example: [check this css trick](https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/) .. (but of course they are needed for links `"http.."` or `"x.jpg"`)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you can do that, you can try to do it with classes instead.

Have a look [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17090571/is-there-a-way-to-set-background-image-as-a-base64-encoded-image-in-javascript#answer-17092083)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line breaks (\r\n) from the base64 string and it should work.