# jquery on click trying to set background-image: url( data:image;base64 for div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here http://jsfiddle.net/m3e1kdzu/9/ is what i am trying

First div is html with `data:image;base64`

```
<div id="large_photo_null" style="width:50px; height:50px; 
background-image: url( data:image;base64,R0lGODlhR..  );" >
</div>
```

With html i see background image as expected.

Now trying to set background image for another div. But no changes. Can not set

Here is code

```
<div id="large_photo" style="width:100px; height:150px;" >
This is as if large photo where expect to change background
</div>

<div class="thbn_photo" style="width:100px; height:150px;" >
As if thumbnail photo. Click here.
</div>
```

Here jquery

```
$(document).on('click', '.thbn_photo', function(){
alert('thbn_photo clicked');

$('#large_photo').css( 'background-image: url( data:image;base64,R0lGODlhRgAzAJEAAMr..  );' );  

});
```

What is wrong? My code is incorrect or with jquery can not set `data:image;base64`?

Now found similar topic [Is there a way to set background-image as a base64 encoded image in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17090571/is-there-a-way-to-set-background-image-as-a-base64-encoded-image-in-javascript)

Will check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's .css() accepts arguments like so:

`$('div').css({'background':'#000'});`

try restructuring your last line there and see if you get different behavior.

Comment: With `background':'#000` works. But how to use `data:image;base64` instead of `#000`.... will try. Thanks for idea

Comment: is this the expected behavior? I modified the last line of the jquery to match mine, also removed the `;` at the end of the background url: http://jsfiddle.net/m3e1kdzu/12/

Answer (score 3):

After 2 hours of fiddling with this, this solution worked for me.

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "data:image/jpeg;charset=utf-8;base64, " + profilepic;
$("#profilepict").css("background-image", "url('" + img.src + "')");
```