# AngularJS: ng-class for dynamic base64 encoded image as background-image

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ng-style

Anyone managed to use ng-class for placing dynamic base64 encoded images as background-images for a div yet? Seems to work for JQuery (see [Is there a way to set background-image as a base64 encoded image in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17090571/is-there-a-way-to-set-background-image-as-a-base64-encoded-image-in-javascript)) but I haven't figured out any solution for AngularJS yet.
This approach of mine does not seem to work out:

```
<div class="col-xs-2" ng-style="{'background-image':'url(data:image/jpeg;base64,{{dynamicImage}})'}">...</div>
```

`dynamicImage` holds the base64 image string which is loaded on the fly via a REST webservice. Any idea if this works at all and how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `{{}}` interpolation inside `ng-style` that will throw an `$parser` error while evaluating that expression. Simply do `string` concatenation inside `ng-style`.

```
<div class="col-xs-2" 
  ng-style="{'background-image':'url(data:image/jpeg;base64,'+dynamicImage+')'}">
```

Comment: Not sure why but the '{{}}' worked well to specify the type i.e. data:image/{{img.type}}    But not for the data itself. So we must use the concatenation only for the data