# Base64 background-image not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to set a div's background to a base64 image dynamically. The base64 image itself is stored in a string variable, base64Image. I am using the following line of code.

```
$("#loadingAdImage").css("background-image", `url("${base64Image}")`);
```

When I inspect the the div element, I find that even though the line was executed, the div has no style attribute. I even tried the following.

```
$("#loadingAdImage").attr("style", `background-image: url('${base64Image}')`);
```

This time when I inspected the div element, I got the style attribute, but the image itself isn't displaying in the background. Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: data:image/png;base64, /9j/4Ry6RXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAA...

The string is quite large so I couldn't include the whole thing.

Comment: Have you seen this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17090571/is-there-a-way-to-set-background-image-as-a-base64-encoded-image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, it shows the images as loaded :-

HTML

```
<div id="test">
```

JS

```
var pic = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAfMAAAHyCAMAAADIj";
// the pic data should be a lot bigger, change it to whatever data you have //
var img = new Image();
img.src = pic;
$("#test").css("background-image", "url('" + img.src + "')");
```

Comment: I don't know why, but this works.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `img` tag for `#loadingAdImage`

then use this code

```js
    $("#loadingAdImage").attr("src", "data:image/png;base64, "+base64Image);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of where this would happen is for `base64Image` to contain a `"` character.

Any other value would set the property correctly given your code:

```js
const sources = [
 "foo bar'¨^*-0+:.?/#`", // many "special" characters but no double quote
 "foo \"bar" // contains a double quote
];
const test = (index) => {
  const source = sources[index];
  console.log(
    { source,
      result: $("#test" + index).css("background-image", `url("${source}")`)
        .attr("style")
    }
  );
};
test(0);
test(1);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test0"></div>
<div id="test1"></div>
```

So double check your `base64Image` value, and remove any `"` in there, it's not part of the base64 encoding characters and it has nothing to do in a base64 encoded data: URL.

Comment: I checked the base64Image value. Unfortunately I did not find any quotes or newline characters to remove.

Comment: Could you paste your code in a https://jsfiddle.net or a https://pastebin.com/ if it's too big even for jsfiddle? Also are you sure the code is actually ran without error to this point?

Comment: Using console.log I was able to confirm that it ran without error. Is it possible that the length of the base64 string might be a factor? It is pretty long. So long in fact that pastebin rejected the post on the basis that it looked like spam.

Comment: No the length should not prevent the setting of the attribute. If you have a github account you can probably create a https://gist.github.com/